# Modeling an interface based on a different interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have some interfaces in TypeScript:

```
export interface IStateA {
  id: number;
}

export interface IStateB {
  text: string;
  moreText: string;
}
```

Is there a way to generate the following interfaces without having to manually do so?

```
export interface IStateASetters {
  setId: (number) => void;
}

export interface IStateBSetters {
  setText: (string) => void;
  setMoreText: (string) => void;
}
```

Note the following:

- the new interface name is the same as the old one, except with `Setters` appended
- the new interface has methods that take in the type of the corresponding property of the old interface
- the new interface method names are the same as the old property names, except with `set` prepended and the first letter of the old name capitalized.

Totally understandable if this isn't possible, partial answers are very welcome!

Comment: I think you want https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html, are you using a new enough version?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html , see remapping section with `as`

Comment: `(string) => void` isn't what you think it is; you need to specify a dummy parameter name like `(value: string) => void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine a mapped type with string literals and key renaming, you can do this.

With something like:

```
type WithSetters<T> = {
     [K in keyof T & string as `set${Capitalize<K>}`]:
          (newValue: T[K]) => void
}
```

The one tricky part here is the `& string`. That's necessary because because a type may have non string keys (numbers, or symbols). But this transformation only makes sense for string keys. So by intersecting the keys with `string` you can be sure to only map the `string` keys.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGUZNUAhOAbwFgAoOOVEGALjgGcYpkBzAbjoMAttGAAVUKw5deA+hwhDgAOQCuQgEZo2SdVqhyAvnTowAnmDwB1BDAAWhYDFRR2AHjEA+OAF4qghgYAbQBpRCQ4AGtgMwh0ODE4ADJpbiQeOEx2OAADdicAEkoAYUwwW0wAGwQAL2A3EM9DHIBdFgDAzrgACiRgAHcANSrVYDYxUJaASl9vADcIBAATOmNaUws8IhJyR2c0bL8bez2Xd23SYDJPOgB6ACo4YABHVQQ5quAURgh22nNLARiJcyKcDr5-PIGPkYBJmGxegNhpVRmxOGkeDMfPNFks5J0YQBZURwqSIoYjMapXhYnHLfGBGGERQqPTaHp9Ckoqm6TRoWlwBb01Z0e63IA)